# z3py: What is the most efficient way of constraining a bit in BitVec?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I have a number of constraints asserting for bits in BitVec and I wonder what is the most efficient way of asserting constraints for a specific bit in a BitVec?

Assume I want to assert that the 5th bit in a BitVec is 1, is there any way that is more efficient (lower check time) than this?

```
bitvec = BitVec('bitvec',10)
s.add(Extract(5,5,bitvec)==1)
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand about the internals of Z3 (from experimenting and looking at the source) this is the most efficient way possible.

As I understand it extracts and concats have no solver runtime cost. They just split the bits into parts.

The only alternative would be to apply an `and` operation to extract the bit. But that should turn into an extract after simplification (which indeed you can test by running the simplify tactic. It's a fun rewrite to observe).

Comment: This is great, I'll try applying bitwise and to extract the bit. Thanks.